# In a binary search tree implemented using a heap, for a node P find the node with the key that is immediately smaller than the key of P

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, heap

In a binary search tree implemented using a heap (so the binary tree is represented using a vector), for a node P find the node with the key that is immediately smaller than the key of P.

For example, here p with key 13, the next smaller key is 11

[image]

I think once you find p you should go once to the left, then go as much to the right as you can

Comment: *binary search tree implemented using a heap* ? those have different purposes although the structure can look similar.

Comment: Yes, that's what I have to do, as an exercise. It doesn't have to be efficient. @SomeDude

Comment: You mean BST implemented using an array in which left, right children are at 2*i+1, 2*i+2 positions where parent is at i ? In that case its *implemented using an array* not *using a heap*.

Comment: Also can you show how you have the BST in the picture represented in an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In a binary search tree implemented using a heap

A heap has different properties:

- A heap is a *complete* binary tree. A BST does not have to be complete (like in the example). The array representation depends on this property. Without it, the array representation is ambiguous: how will the "gaps" be represented?
- The children of a heap node have values that are not less than the node's value (when it's a min-heap), while the left child of a BST node (if any) has a value that is not greater than the node's value

In the end the data structure is just a detail when looking at this question.

> I think once you find p you should go once to the left, then go as much to the right as you can

That is one scenario. It is indeed correct when p *has* a left child. If not, you should go upward until you move upward from a *right* child. Then you have arrived at the preceding node.

### Code

I assume that the representation as array will have following characteristics:

- The array will dynamically grow as needed
- Unused array entries will get a reserved value (`undefined`)

Here is an implementation of that in JavaScript:

```js
class BST extends Array {
    add(value) {
        let i = 0;
        while (i < this.length && this[i] !== undefined) {
            let nodeValue = this[i];
            i = i * 2 + 1;
            if (value >= nodeValue) {
                i++;
            }
        }
        // Extend array ... although JS would do this automatically..
        while (this.length <= i) {
            this.push(undefined);
        }
        this[i] = value;
        return this;
    }
    predecessor(i) {
        // if has left child...
        let child = i * 2 + 1;
        if (child < this.length && this[child] !== undefined) {
            // then find right most descendent
            while (child < this.length && this[child] !== undefined) {
                i = child;
                child = child * 2 + 2;
            }
            return i;
        }
        // otherwise, while it is a left child, go up
        while (i % 2 == 1) {
            i = (i - 1) / 2; 
        }
        if (i > 0) { // not the root, but a right child of a parent
            return (i - 2) / 2;
        }
        // We reached the root... there is no predecessor
        return -1;
    }
}

// Demo
let bst = new BST();
// Load example tree
bst.add(16).add(7).add(6).add(13).add(10).add(8).add(11);
// Find node with value 16
let i = bst.indexOf(16);
// Keep walking to the node that precedes it...
while (i >= 0) {
    console.log(`bst[${i}] == ${bst[i]}`);
    i = bst.predecessor(i);
}
```

Note how the used indexes of the array are quite spread out: lots of entries are actually "gaps", i.e. unused entries.

Comment: And what is the complexity of this algorithm?

Comment: One call of `predecessor` has an average time complexity of O(1) and worst time complexity of O(). The `while` loop at the bottom, including  calls of `predecessor`, has a time complexity of O().